# Print out set of data inside a text file in java

Tags: java

I have a text file which contains this data.

```
<Equity Chart>
2004-01-21 00:00,100000.00
2004-02-21 00:00,-9950.00
2004-03-20 00:00,-4250.00


<Summary Table>
Net Profit=-$101,100.00
Total Trades=2
Wins=0
Losses=2
Aborted Entries=0
Fatal Errors=0
Win Rate=0.00%
Max Draw Down=-$104,250.00
Gross Profit=$0.00
Gross Loss=-$101,100.00
Profit Factor=0.0
Max Consecutive Wins=0
Max Consecutive Losses=2
Peak Risk=$inf
Average Risk=$inf
Return On Avg. Risk=0.00%
Average Win Size=N/A
Average Loss Size=-$50,550.00
Avg. Win: Avg. Loss=N/A
Largest Win=N/A
Largest Loss=-$93,650.00
Max DIT=2
Min DIT=2
Average DIT=2.0


<Table Of Trades>
"Expiration","Entry Date","Exit Date","DIT","PnL","Peak Risk","Return on Risk","Opening Balance","Closing Balance","Starting IV","Ending IV","IV Change","IV Change Pct.","Starting UL Price","Ending UL Price","Price Movement","Price Movement STDEV","Adjustments"
"21-Feb-04","02-Feb-04","03-Feb-04","2","-$93,650.00","$inf","-0.00%","$100,000.00","-$9,950.00","0.14","0.15","0.0","1.64%","$1,135.26","$1,136.79","$1.53","0.13","13"
"20-Mar-04","01-Mar-04","02-Mar-04","2","-$7,450.00","$inf","-0.00%","$6,350.00","-$4,250.00","0.12","0.12","-0.0","-3.19%","$1,155.97","$1,156.26","$0.29","0.03","2"
```

I want each group to be printed out separately like,

```
System.out.print(<Equity Chart>);
output: 2004-01-21 00:00,100000.00
       2004-02-21 00:00,-9950.00
       2004-03-20 00:00,-4250.00
```

same goes with (Summary Table) and (Table Of Trades). how do I achieved that?

this is by far the code that I have created.

```
File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName+".txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(newFile);
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();      
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Must be homework time!  I would suggest you have a String buffer, read in the line (like you are doing) then have some if statement that says "If the line starts with '<' and ends with '>', print the current buffer if there is one and create a new empty buffer", then add your read in line to the buffer.

Comment: I do actually work from home so, yes, it's a homework... ^_^.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some idea from this

```
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(new File("/home/ruchira/Text.txt"));
    StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sb2=new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sb3=new StringBuilder();
    String line1=new String();
    String line2=new String();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        if(scanner.nextLine().equals("<Equity Chart>")){
             while(!(line1=scanner.nextLine()).equals("<Summary Table>")){
                 sb1.append(line1+"\n");
             }
        } else if(line1.equals("<Summary Table>")){
            while(!(line2=scanner.nextLine()).equals("<Table Of Trades>")){
                sb2.append(line2+"\n");
            }
            line1="";
        }else if(line2.equals("<Table Of Trades>")){
               while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                   sb3.append(scanner.nextLine()+"\n") ;
               }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("<Equity Chart>\n"+sb1.toString().trim());
    System.out.println("=====================================");
    System.out.println("<Summary Table>\n"+sb2.toString().trim());
    System.out.println("=====================================");
    System.out.println("<Table Of Trades>\n"+sb3.toString().trim());
```

Comment: A `Map<String, List>` with checking for `<.*>` would probably be preferred. Though we don't really like just giving someone a complete solution if they hadn't attempted to solve it themselves.

Comment: @Dukeling, I did try to solve them but they did not work. my mistake is that I deleted all the codes that I have tried and did not include it in here. I was just hoping that I could get some idea for an answer and not expecting a complete solution from Ruchira. ^_^